# password param not being included in strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Bcrypt with has_secure_password in my User class, and trying to create a new User with username and password, but the password param, although permitted in my strong params, is not coming through.

This is my User class:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  has_many :journals
end
```

This is the User Controller:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ActionController::API
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users.to_json(:include => :journals)
  end

  def create
    byebug
    @user = User.create(user_params)
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
  end
end
```

I'm trying to post a new user with:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/users', {
method: 'POST', 
headers: {Accept: 'application/json', "Content-Type": 
'application/json'}, 
body: JSON.stringify({username: 'Name', password: 'test'})})
```

and the result, inside the byebug in 'create', is:

```
(byebug) params
<ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"Name", "password"=>"test", 
"controller"=>"api/v1/users", "action"=>"create", "user"=> . 
{"username"=>"Name"}} permitted: false>
(byebug) user_params
<ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"Name"} permitted: true>
```

No matter what I try, I cannot access the password param in user_params to create a user with a hashed password.

In terminal, in rails console, I can create a user and the password gets hashed as expected, I can then fetch that user information from the API with a normal fetch request, but I cannot use strong params to create a User with a Post request, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> but I cannot use strong params to create a User with a Post request, and I don't know why.

Mainly because you're not using strong params correctly.

```
params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
```

This means that you need to pass `{user: {username: 'foo', password: 'bar'}}` instead of `{username: 'foo', password: 'bar'}` (see the nesting?).

But even though you don't pass `params[:user][:username]`, it is somehow magically there. How? [`ParamsWrapper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html), that's how.

> If you enable ParamsWrapper for :json format, instead of having to send JSON parameters like this:
>
> ```
> {"user": {"name": "Konata"}}
> ```
>
> You can send parameters like this:
>
> ```
> {"name": "Konata"}
> ```

Yes, but why `password` doesn't get the same treatment? We find out a few lines below:

> On Active Record models with no `:include` or `:exclude` option set, it will only wrap the parameters returned by the class method `attribute_names`.

`password` is not an attribute/column in your model, so params wrapper ignores it.

Comment: @robert did this help?

Comment: Thank you!  That explained it perfectly.  I wasn't aware of ParamsWrapper and thought I was missing something about how to use has_secure_password.

Comment: First question I’ve asked, didn’t realize I had to. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Mystery solved!